# Suspicious html script, might be a cookie stealer

Tags: javascript, html

A friend of mine, who I trust, sent me a link and I without realizing it clicked it, it redirected to a bunch of ads, he admitted that he had been hacked and that the "hacker" sent this link to all of his contacts.

I wanted to know what this html script does, I am suspicious that it's a cookie stealer.

**WARNING: Please do not run this script as I am not sure what it really does.**

The link had the format of: http://www.domain.tk/#id=skypename

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html>
  <head>
    <title>scant-824.tk</title>
    <meta name="description" content="scant-824.tk">
    <meta name="keywords" content="scant-824.tk">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-23441223-3']);
        _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
        _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        (function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();
    </script>
  </head>
  <frameset rows="*">
    <frame frameborder=0 src="http://www. baidu. com/link?url=FOegyucrzCZDSsrEXSFhN6idOgPNBB_7bBhNJfl7_WvRU1lBWazaftDY8q1BwXY0" name="dot_tk_frame_content" scrolling="auto" noresize>
  </frameset>
</html>
```

**WARNING: Please do not run this script as I am not sure what it really does.**

My conclusions are that this script has a google analytics tracker, and that it has a frame which adopts ads from baidu. Not sure about the "document.getelementsbytagname"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script itself is from Google Analytics, which is just tracking how many visitors you got. Google Analytics lazy loads the actual tracking code appending the script to the `script`-Tag with `getElementsByTagName`.

The actual attack (if any) might happen in the frame.

Comment: Attack? Well, that depends on the browser.

Comment: Yea, I just checked the frame's link and it's just filled with ad redirections

Comment: @Lumio But anyways... the location where the script runs probably doesn't have access to other external locations/sites (cross-origin), turning out that no attack is possible, except that the IP might be taken...

Comment: @TheProHands It might be a skype ip dox?

Comment: @PhysiOSQuantum No, your network IP (which is requisitioning)

Comment: Well the most-used browsers, their API don't offer so far access to processes :v